# Pulling Data from File Generated From GoogleSheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have created the following data file and using JavaScript code calling a google spreadsheet. I am lost on how to get the information that is stored within this file and use it as values with my JavaScript code.

The file I am trying to get values from is below:
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1ayp5hzHWVk_Gj9-lhzNULOrMof2BVFk3PlAmCtyfeKw/od6/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=sheet

My issue is that I have no idea how to take any of the information from this file and the entire thing looks like gibberish to me because of my limited coding experience. Any help and explanation of how to go about this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/duapqq/use-a-google-spreadsheet-as-your-json-backend

Comment: <script src="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1ayp5hzHWVk_Gj9-lhzNULOrMof2BVFk3PlAmCtyfeKw/od6/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=sheet"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function importGSS(json) {
        console.log('finished');
    }
</script>

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do this manually, there are libraries that lets you fetch information from google spreadsheets. Check out this for starters: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Comment: This set libraries is saying that I can add features to google sheets when I want the data from the sheet to use as a java script variable on a separate website. Am I correct in this interpretation or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, I think so. But check out Vasim Vanzara's link too, in the comments to your question. It seems to be more practical.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to take a crack at it!